# Error when executing : dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

Tags: flutter, firebase, configure

please ,
When I execute this commande
**dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli**

i have this message :

**Warning: Executable "flutterfire" runs "bin\flutterfire.dart", which was not found in flutterfire_cli.**

and the same error when i execute this command

**FlutterFire configure**

**Could not find bin\flutterfire.dart in package flutterfire_cli.**

just to configure firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy/paste your command in my terminal everything works ok.

```
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
+ ansi_styles 0.3.2+1s... (1.6s)
+ args 2.3.1
+ async 2.9.0 (2.10.0 available)
+ characters 1.2.1
+ ci 0.1.0
+ cli_util 0.3.5
+ clock 1.1.1
+ collection 1.17.0
+ dart_console 1.1.2
+ deep_pick 0.10.0
+ ffi 2.0.1
+ file 6.1.4
+ flutterfire_cli 0.2.7
+ http 0.13.5
+ http_parser 4.0.2
+ interact 2.1.1
+ intl 0.17.0
+ json_annotation 4.7.0
+ matcher 0.12.12 (0.12.13 available)
+ meta 1.8.0
+ path 1.8.2
+ petitparser 5.0.0 (5.1.0 available)
+ platform 3.1.0
+ process 4.2.4
+ pub_semver 2.1.2
+ pub_updater 0.2.2
+ pubspec 2.3.0
+ quiver 3.1.0
+ source_span 1.9.1
+ stack_trace 1.10.0 (1.11.0 available)
+ string_scanner 1.1.1 (1.2.0 available)
+ term_glyph 1.2.1
+ tint 2.0.0
+ typed_data 1.3.1
+ uri 1.0.0
+ win32 2.7.0 (3.1.1 available)
+ xml 6.1.0 (6.2.2 available)
+ yaml 3.1.1
Downloading flutterfire_cli 0.2.7...
Downloading interact 2.1.1...
Downloading deep_pick 0.10.0...
Downloading ci 0.1.0...
Downloading ansi_styles 0.3.2+1...
Downloading pubspec 2.3.0...
Downloading uri 1.0.0...
Downloading dart_console 1.1.2...
Downloading win32 2.7.0...
Downloading ffi 2.0.1...
Building package executables... (1.7s)
Built flutterfire_cli:flutterfire.
Installed executable flutterfire.
Activated flutterfire_cli 0.2.7.
```

I suppose problem in your dev machine environment

Comment: dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

Package flutterfire_cli is currently active at version 0.2.7.
Resolving dependencies...
The package flutterfire_cli is already activated at newest available version.
To recompile executables, first run `dart pub global deactivate flutterfire_cli`.
Installed executable flutterfire.
Warning: Executable "flutterfire" runs "bin\flutterfire.dart", which was not found in flutterfire_cli.
Activated flutterfire_cli 0.2.7.

Comment: I think this is silly question but I have to ask.Did you try run **dart pub global deactivate flutterfire_cli** and reinstall it?

Comment: npm uninstall -g firebase-tools
    npm install -g firebase-tools
    dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli, and i have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by reinstalling dart as follows:

```
brew tap dart-lang/dart
brew install dart
```